# Size() method on SpiceJet.com website is giving incorrect result

Tags: size

I am trying below selenium code to click on a specific checkbox.

```
package com;


import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class KnownCheckBoxes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("Window Maximized");
        List<WebElement> count = driver.findElements(By.id("discount-checkbox"));
        System.out.println(count.size());// Always giving count as 1
        int size = count.size();

        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
            WebElement discount = count.get(i);
            String s = discount.getText();
            System.out.println(s);// Printing all the check boxes value and not going inside below loop.
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(" Indian Armed Forces")){
                System.out.println(discount);
                driver.findElements(By.id("discount-checkbox")).get(i).click();
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

The Output it is giving is as below.

Window Maximized
1
Family and Friends
Senior Citizen
Indian Armed Forces
Student
Unaccompanied Minor

Comment: can you share the html around discount-checkbox? Seems like your selector is incorrect

Comment: The HTML goes as below

Comment: <div class="row1 padding-bottom-3 home-dis-checkboxes" id="discount-checkbox">
 <div id="familyandfriend" class="fleft  home-StudentDiscount tooltip home-Discount home-Discount1">
  <a class="tool_info mobile-tooltip icon-margin">
   <span class="search-offer-tooltip mobile-tooltip-left">Family and Friends discount is applicable for a minimum of four passenger (excluding infant) on a single booking, Terms and conditions apply.
   </span>                                    
  </a>

Comment: <input id="ctl00_mainContent_chk_friendsandfamily" name="ctl00$mainContent$chk_friendsandfamily" type="checkbox">
  <label for="ctl00_mainContent_chk_friendsandfamily"> Family and Friends</label>
 </div>
 
 <div id="ctl00_mainContent_SeniorCitizenDiv" class="fleft  home-StudentDiscount tooltip home-Discount home-Discount4">
  <a class="tool_info mobile-tooltip icon-margin">

Comment: <span class="search-offer-tooltip mobile-tooltip-left">The special discounted fares are applicable only to the Senior citizens. A valid age proof is a necessary condition for travel under this offer and passengers will be required to produce the identity card at the SpiceJet check in counter at the airport.
   </span>
  </a>
  <input id="ctl00_mainContent_chk_SeniorCitizenDiscount" name="ctl00$mainContent$chk_SeniorCitizenDiscount" type="checkbox">
  <label for="ctl00_mainContent_chk_SeniorCitizenDiscount"> Senior Citizen</label>
 </div>

Comment: <div id="ctl00_mainContent_studentAndDefense" style="margin-top: 0px;" class="fleft  home-StudentDiscount tooltip home-Discount home-Discount2">
  <div id="ctl00_mainContent_IndArm" class="fleft home-StudentDiscount tooltip home-Discount home-Discount3 IAF-mobile">
    <input id="ctl00_mainContent_chk_IndArm" name="ctl00$mainContent$chk_IndArm" type="checkbox">
    <label for="ctl00_mainContent_chk_IndArm"> Indian Armed Forces</label>

Comment: <a class="tool_info mobile-tooltip icon-margin">
    <span class="search-offer-tooltip mobile-tooltip-left">Applicable for all serving and retired Indian Armed Forces personnel, Paramilitary Forces personnel and their dependent families. Limited inventory available. Valid photo ID and relevant military card need to be presented for verification at check-in. Conditions apply.
    </span>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: <div id="StudentDiv" class="fleft  home-StudentDiscount tooltip home-Discount home-Discount2">
   <a class="tool_info mobile-tooltip icon-margin">
    <span class="search-offer-tooltip mobile-tooltip-left">Applicable for all students above the age of 12 years studying with a bonafide school/university. Limited inventory available. Valid photo ID and educational institute I-card need to be presented for verification at check-in. Bookings under this offer are refundable. Conditions apply.
    </span>
   </a>

Comment: <input id="ctl00_mainContent_chk_StudentDiscount" name="ctl00$mainContent$chk_StudentDiscount" type="checkbox">
   <label for="ctl00_mainContent_chk_StudentDiscount"> Student</label>
 </div>
 <div id="UnmrDiv" class="fleft  home-StudentDiscount tooltip home-Discount home-Discount5">
   <a class="tool_info mobile-tooltip icon-margin">

Comment: <span class="search-offer-tooltip mobile-tooltip-left">Children between the ages of 5 and under 12 years who will be traveling alone are considered unaccompanied minors A fee of Rs.1500/Rs.3000 (Domestic and International respectively) will be applicable each way per unaccompanied minor. Once booked, please fill the 'Unaccompanied Minor form' available on our website. Print 4 copies of the same and bring them with you to the airport.
    </span>

Comment: </a>
   <input id="ctl00_mainContent_chk_Unmr" name="ctl00$mainContent$chk_Unmr" type="checkbox">
   <label for="ctl00_mainContent_chk_Unmr">Unaccompanied Minor</label>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: please, can you update the code in your question, it is difficult to follow